# Columns with Sequence Number

Tags: sql, duplicates, db2, unique, sequence

```
create table Account(A_number number, B_number number, C_number, A_number_mask number as 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, B_number_mask number, C_number_mask )
```

after the insert the table values are

```
A_number B_number  C_number A_mask_number B_mask C_mask
10        100      200      1             NULL   NULL
20        100      200      2             NULL   NULL
30        101      201      3             NULL   NULL
40        102      202      4             NULL   NULL
50        103      203      5             NULL   NULL
60        101      201      6             NULL   NULL
```

now I have to populate

- B_number_mask  for B_number
- C_number_mask  for C-number

When I mask or create a sequence the new column also should have repeated values for the repeated values in parent column.

the output should be like:

```
A_number B_number  C_number A_mask_number B_mask C_mask
10        100      200      1             1      1000
20        100      200      2             1      1000
30        101      201      3             2      2000 
40        102      202      4             3      3000
50        103      203      5             4      4000    
60        101      201      6             2      2000
```

I have to give the sequenced columns to the users instead of the parent columns.
Please feel free to use any start number for the sequence.

Comment: Show us how you create your second table and how you populated

Comment: Hi i have not created the second table. I would like this output on my second table. for A_number_mask i can use a sequence while creating the 2nd table which I can show instead of A_number for security purpose. but I dont know what logic i should try for B_mask_number as it has duplicates. I need a sequence or unique values based on B_number provided I get same B_number_mask for the duplicate B_number

Comment: Explain what you want to achieve. Right now I cant understand the logic.Is English your main language? Because if you say "I Have" mean is already done , instead "I Want" or "I Need" meen you need help with that

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. English is not my main language and I'm trying my best to explain my requirement. 
for A_number and B_number I want to create a random unique number. So that I do not have to give the actual value to the company for security purpose. I can create unique number for A_number by using sequence. But B_number is having duplicate value if I use sequence I will get different value for same B_number values which I don't want. So if there is any other way to achieve the requirement with SQL kindly guide me.

Comment: well try to use google translator next time. We also have SO in other languages, that may help. But I will try to answer your question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to create a sequence.

```
SELECT A_number,
       B_number,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RAND()) as A_number_mask, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B_number ORDER BY RAND()) as B_number_mask
FROM Account
```

Comment: my requirement needs numbers in different series. our data has A_number in series of 1000000000,2000000000 and so on. but it does not have 5000000000 series. so in my sequence i will be using this series to get unique value. same way we do not have a series 7000000000 for B_number. i will have to use this series to get the unique number based on B_number.

Comment: try with row_)number

Comment: Okay I will try this aggregate

Comment: `ORDER BY rand()` is nice because help you conceal the relationship between rows. But maybe will cause performance issues if table is too big. So take that into consideration.

Answer (score -1):

You could use identity columns to geneate the unique number automatically when inserting the data

```
create table Account_New(A_number number,
                         B_number number,
                         A_number_mask BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH -1, INCREMENT BY -1)
                         B_number_mask BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 7000000000, INCREMENT BY 1)
)
```

Just two options to show possibilities - the one is generating negative numbers the other one is using your unused series.

Comment: A table can have only one column defined with the IDENTITY property.
and here B_number is not unique. B_number_mask should be created based on B_number and it should give the duplicate sequence number for a duplicate B_number. for example if B_number is 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4 then B_mask_number should be 700, 701, 702, 702, 702, 703. and i do not want to use arithmetic operation. if there is any other way to achieve this tell me

Comment: Sorry true - but you could define one sequences instead the second identity column